# How to have our App Store listed app auto-upgrade to latest version on "supervised" iPads (or remotely upgrade the app to latest version)

Tags: ipad, applications, ios-appstore, software-update, mobile-device-management

We develop a b2b iOS app that is publicly listed on Apple Store.

We lease our clients iPads so that they can use our app. We have full access and ownership of these iPads and we are able to "prepare" them before sending them off to our clients.

Our aim is to have our app always upgrade to the latest released version, even on mobile network (we deliver the iPads with LTE-capable eSims pre-installed).

Our first approach was:
use Apple Configurator to make iPads "supervised", manually "install the app" from computer to which the iPad is connected, apply configuration profile to not allow the app to be deleted, and set App Store config to "update apps even on mobile network".

This seems to have not worked – 1 week after the new release, our analytics report that these iPads are still on the previous version.

Is there some other way, maybe using MDM or something like that to either make the apps auto-upgrade or to manually remotely have the iPads upgrade the apps to latest App Store version?

Thank you!